# Microsoft Teams - Audiocodes SBC with wildcard certificate?

Tags: office365, voip, microsoft-teams, tls1.2, pbx

Dear colleagues and visitors,

I am trying to manage the Audiocodes Mediant VE SBC, in order to connect Microsoft Teams tenant to my PBX. I have already configured all the settings on SIP side (S+C), Teams side has O+M+P configuration.

The problem shows up, when it is needed to set Device and all the other certificates on Audiocodes Mediant VE.
I am using a wildcard certificate, already used on plenty of servers/websites. But, Teams are not accepting TLS connection from my SBC.
If I am using a wildcard certificate - CSR generating is not needed, only the upload is, right?
I have also to mention, that the root CA file is uploaded in proper place, along with the wildcard on the main Certificates page.

Where did I the wrong thing, does anyone have any experience in configuring the SBC with wildcard certificate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Team is investigating on this and is forwarded to the right channel.

Comment: For quieres related to teams product, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to renew the SSL cert, according to the youtube/doc, I just need to upload the new wildcard cert under "Change Cert". The trusted root certificate is from MS Teams. That's how I understand it.